# Developer story GitHub stats are not dynamic

Tags: support, feature-request, developer-story

Okay, so I know that this issue may not be new, but I thought I'd point it out and check your guys opinion. I noticed that one GitHub project that I have on my developer story isn't getting updated with newer commits and data.

Is there a way to fix that? For example with a hook from GitHub maybe?

Thanks.